# How to sjoin using geopandas using a common key column and also location

Tags: python, geopandas

Suppose I have dataframe A which consists of two columns : geometry ( point) and also hour.
dataframe B also consists of geometry(shape) and hour.

I am familiar with standard sjoin . What I want to do is to make sjoin link rows from the two tables only when the hours are the **same**.  In traditional join terminology the keys are geometry and hour. How can I attain it?

Comment: Please do add some sample dataframes.

Comment: are you familiar with relational databases and how QEPs are constructed for complex joins?  using that logic of join then filter it will be straight forward.  i.e. do spatial join first, then filter than interim result to where hour is same.  I can code up an example if it's not clear

Comment: @Rob Raymond 
That's what I'm doing now. The problem is, it is vastly inefficient because it is geo-matching on every possible pair in first stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have reviewed two logical approached

- spatial join followed by filter
- shard (filter) data frames first on **hour**, spatial join shards and concatenate results from the sharded data frames
- test results for equality
- run some timings

Conclusions

- little difference between timings on this test data set. **simple** is quicker if number of points is small

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import requests

# source some points and polygons
# fmt: off
dfp = pd.read_html("https://www.latlong.net/category/cities-235-15.html")[0]
dfp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfp, geometry=dfp.loc[:,["Longitude", "Latitude",]].apply(shapely.geometry.Point, axis=1))
res = requests.get("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/69dc11c7386943b4ad8893c45648b1e1_0.geojson")
df_poly = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(res.json())
# fmt: on
# bulk up number of points
dfp = pd.concat([dfp for _ in range(1000)]).reset_index()
HOURS = 24
dfp["hour"] = np.random.randint(0, HOURS, len(dfp))
df_poly["hour"] = np.random.randint(0, HOURS, len(df_poly))

def simple():
    return gpd.sjoin(dfp, df_poly).loc[lambda d: d["hour_left"] == d["hour_right"]]

def shard():
    return pd.concat(
        [
            gpd.sjoin(*[d.loc[d["hour"].eq(h)] for d in [dfp, df_poly]])
            for h in range(HOURS)
        ]
    )

print(f"""length test: {len(simple()) == len(shard())} {len(simple())}
dataframe test: {simple().sort_index().equals(shard().sort_index())}
points: {len(dfp)}
polygons: {len(df_poly)}""")

%timeit simple()
%timeit shard()
```

#### output

```
length test: True 3480
dataframe test: True
points: 84000
polygons: 379
6.48 s ± 311 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
4.05 s ± 34.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. So I'd go with the simple one.

Comment: it really depends on your data which one performs best. worth testing both, each are fairly pretty straight forward