# Geopandas: joining by nearest with matching id field

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I have a line df and a point df.

I want to join the attributes of line features to the nearest point features, but only when the 'id' fields from both df's are matching

I can join by nearest using the sjoin_nearest geopandas function.

> geopandas.sjoin_nearest(point_df, line_df, distance_col="distances")

But I am not sure how I could add the ability to only join to features that have a matching id field

Comment: this you'll have to do with a groupby or loop. there's no dual spatial-and-other-col merge in geopandas. implementing the loop solution should be as straightforward as it sounds, but if you need any help gettting it across the finish line, a [mre] and more info about your specific case would be very helpful.

Comment: I have previously answered this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69610731/how-to-sjoin-using-geopandas-using-a-common-key-column-and-also-location/69635575#69635575